Issues in SCDF upgrade from spring boot 2.7.18 to 3.1.0
I am upgrading my existing scdf application from spring boot 2.7.18 to 3.1.0. I am facing below error during start-up.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/wavefront/WavefrontProperties
at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.config.MetricsReplicationEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(MetricsReplicationEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:107).
I see i have a org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.wavefront.WavefrontProperties in my class path.
When i say scdf spring boot with 2.7.18 version, I mean parent for my scdf app is spring boot 2.7.18
my scdf app works fine with spring boot 2.7.18. As soon as i upgrade to 3.1.0 its erroring out

Hi there! Please read how to ask for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow.

Existing SCDF 2.11.3 or earlier will not work with Spring Boot 3.x
You can create task/batch or stream apps using the Boot 3.x and orchestrate those with SCDF 2.11.x.
You cannot consume any SCDF 2.x libraries in a Boot 3.x application.
